# How can I get the value of a registry key with a batch script and display value in decimal

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to display the value using a script i found in a previous post which works except it gives me the value in Hexadecimal. I need it in Decimal.

```
@echo OFF

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version8
set VALUE_NAME=ClientID

FOR /F "tokens=1-3" %%A IN ('REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul') DO (
set ValueName=%%A
set ValueType=%%B
set ValueValue=%%C
)

if defined ValueName (
@echo Value Name = %ValueName%
@echo Value Type = %ValueType%
@echo Value Value = %ValueValue%
) else (
@echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
)
```

Any help would be greatly be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

```
SET /a valuevalue=0x0%valuevalue%
```

needs to be inserted before the `if defined` valuename` line.

The `/a` tells set to work in arithmetic mode. The `0x` means that the number is in hexadecimal. the following `0` ensures that the number provided is valid in the case that `valuevalue` is empty, but otherwise does not affect the value of `valuevalue`.

See set/? from the prompt for documentation.